# react production build subroutes gives 404 on nginx server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a react monorepo app production build deployed on a VM on port 3001 using docker

i also have a docker container which basically sets up reverse proxy for all deployed applications and services using default.conf file , it is an nginx reverse proxy config container

this is the config i have written for it

in the default.conf of nginx container

```
location /monorepo/ {
        #rewrite ^/monorepo(.*)$ $1 break;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.html break;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_pass  http://172.16.22.100:3001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header HTTPS true;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

since this reverse proxy is /monorepo/

i had change my homeroute to /monorepo/

for home route that is /monorepo/
my react app production build homepage is served properly

but on subroutes if i refresh it shows 404 page of nginx

how can i solve this?

i tried multiple solutions like redirecting to /monorepo/ for all subroutes but it doesnt work
i am new to nginx but very much familiar with react